# NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngclass' since it isn't a known property of 'span'

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

> error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngclass' since it isn't a known property of 'span'.

My Zippy.component.html file is

```html
<div class="zippy">
  <div class="zippy-heading"

       [class.expanded]="isExpanded"
       (click)="onClick()"
  >
    {{ title }}

    <span class="glyphicon"
          [ngclass]="{
                'glyphicon-chevron-up':isExpanded,
                'glyphicon-chevron-down':!isExpanded
            }"
    >

        </span>

  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isExpanded" class="zippy-body">
    <ng-content>

    </ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The correct word is `ngClass`, with uppercase `C`.

Answer (score 0):

use `ngClass` instead of `ngclass`.

Check out the documentation here.
https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass